# Help to understand "her Las Vegas Piece of Me residency billboards"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, terminology

I don't quite understand "her Las Vegas Piece of Me residency billboards" in the sentence below.

> The looks are often so showstopping that clients tend to save them for stage performances and fashion shows — Gathercole even designed Britney Spears’s ensembles for all **her Las Vegas Piece of Me residency billboards**.

Source: [Mel B's totally see-through jumpsuit will make you do a double take](https://www.yahoo.com/style/mel-b-wears-totally-see-jumpsuit-americas-got-talent-145321668.html)

"Piece of Me" should be the title of something. In fact, the part I don't get is "residency billboards".

Comment: What is the source? "Piece of Me" is a title of something.

Comment: "Piece of Me" should be the title of something. In fact, the part I don't get is "residency billboards".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *residency billboard* is a billboard that promotes a [residency show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residency_show).

> A residency show is a series of concerts (typically of live music), similar to a concert tour, but only performed at one location.
>   (Wikipedia)

Her residency show was [*Britney: Piece of Me*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Britney:_Piece_of_Me) in Las Vegas, Nevada, USA.